# Getting permission not granted in GingerBread

Tags: android, permissions, external, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am using following function to check whether read from external storage permission has been granted or not.

```
public static boolean checkWritePermissions(Context context)
{   String permission = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    int res = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

The function is working correctly for post GingerBread devices, however for GingerBread devices the returned value is false. Ignoring the function returned value shows that permission has been granted. Is there any alternative for GingerBread devices.

P.S.: The application isn't using Support Library so new permission methods aren't being used.

Comment: just check if the api version is >= marshmallow if not then you have permission

Comment: If in case the permission isn't written in the manifest, basically I am developing a library.

Comment: if you are developing the library then just add the permission to your manifest, then when the module is imported via gradle or manually the permissions are automatically merged with the app

Comment: There are many devices which do no have External Storage Medium, If I add the permission tags in manifest, would it affect the visibility of application to those devices.

Comment: all devices have "External Storage" you either have a sd-card or you have a simulated external storage but still acts the same as an sdcard

Comment: Thanks..!, I will add permissions in library's manifest...